# How to allocate arrays of arrays in structure with CUDA Fortran?

Tags: arrays, cuda, fortran, pgi

With CUDA, I'm trying to allocate arrays in a structure, but I'm having an issue and I don't know why. So here is a short code (stored in a file called `struct.cuf`) that describe my problem. I'm compiling with the `PGI 16.10 version`, and I'm using the following options : `-O3 -Mcuda=cc60 -tp=x64 struct.cuf -o struct_out`

```
module structure
contains

type mytype
 integer :: alpha,beta,gamma
 real,dimension(:),pointer :: a
end type mytype

type mytypeDevice
 integer :: alpha,beta,gamma
 real,dimension(:),pointer,device :: a
end type mytypeDevice

end module structure

program main
 use cudafor
 use structure

 type(mytype) :: T(3)
 type(mytypeDevice),device :: T_Device(3)

 ! For the host
 do i=1,3
  allocate(T(i)%a(10))
 end do
 T(1)%a=1; T(2)%a=2; T(3)%a=3

 ! For the device
 print *, 'Everything from now is ok'
 do i=1,3
  allocate(T_Device(i)%a(10))
 end do
 !do i=1,3
 ! T_Device(i)%a=T(i)%a
 !end do

end program main
```

The output error :

```
 Everything from now is ok
Segmentation fault
```

**What I am doing wrong here ?**

The only solution I found (and working) is to stored the values in differents arrays and transfers them to the GPU, but it's very "Heavy". Mostly if I use a lot of structures like mytype.

EDIT : Code has been modified to use Vladimir F's solution. If I remove the `device` attribute from `T_Device(3)` declaration, then allocation seems ok and giving values too (commented lines below allocation). But I need that `device` attribute for `T_Device(3)`, because I'm gonna use it in kernels.

Thanks !

Comment: From http://www.pgroup.com/doc/pgi17cudaforug.pdf (the link of Vladimir F): "Members of a derived type may not have the device attribute unless they are allocatable." Also, you give the "device" attribute both to "a" and to "T_Device", making a nested "device" attribute. This certainly complicates your issue: set a single level for the "device" attribute.

Comment: yes it works with just one "device" attribute. But if I remove this attributes off `T_Device(3)`, I can't use `T_Device(3)` in kernels...

Answer (score 1):

I think you need a device pointer

```
type mytype_device
 ...
 real,dimension(:),pointer, device :: a
end type
```

Never used CUDA Fortran in my life, but it seems obvious enough to wager.

Comment: I tried this solution too ! But It's not working, I get the same error... By the way, the attribute "pointer" doesn't match with the attribute "device" in fortran PGI, you have to use "allocatable" instead.

Comment: What is your resource for the fact that you cannot use `pointer` for device? I looked into some PGI presentation and they used it. For example 2.12.3 in http://www.pgroup.com/doc/pgi17cudaforug.pdf

Comment: Allocatable should always be preferred, but that is a general rule in Fortran, not CUDA.

Comment: Otherwise, if you still have a segfault, it looks quite clear we need a [mcve]. A couple of lines is not enough. Prepare a full and compilable code which is short and segfaults.

Comment: My bad, yes the `pointer` attributes works too. I tried it also but it leads always to the same error. I will prepare a short code tomorrow that underline my problem, thanks anyway for your attention !

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is how you have declared `T_Device`. To use host side allocation you first populate a *host* memory copy of the device structure, and then copy it to device memory. This:

```
type(mytypeDevice) :: T_Device(3)

do i=1,3
  allocate(T_Device(i)%a(10))
 end do
```

will work correctly. This is a *very* standard design pattern in C++ based CUDA code, and the principle here is identical.

Comment: So there shouldn't any any device pointers stored in a device derived type? Because if I try that (just installed PIG Community) I get `PGF90-S-0519-More than one device-resident object in assignment`

Comment: @VladimirF: No there *are* device pointers within the derived type. But the derived type itself resides in host memory when those device pointers are allocated in host code. You can then copy that host instance to an instance in device memory.

Comment: Yes, I got that. Your code worked fine. But If I want to get a structure containing a device pointer to be on the device? Do I have to do such things in a kernel?

Comment: declare a device memory instance of `mytypeDevice` and copy to it from a populated host memory instance

Comment: That's exactly what I am trying. If I find time I might create a question about that.

Comment: Ok so I can't use `T_Device` in my kernels. If I understand, I need to declare for example `type(mytypeDevice),device :: T_Device2(3)` and then I take the infos from T_Device ? I will try, but correct me if I'm wrong.